# If else statement for changing color in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, youtube, vimeo

http://jsfiddle.net/alexruff/Vrxv9/3/

I have 2 buttons, one for vimeo one for youtube. Those buttons toggle the 2 videos with a right to left movement.

I want to highlight (change color) the youtube button when the youtube video is shown (marginLeft: '0'), and the vimeo button when the vimeo video is shown (marginLeft: '-1000px').

I tried using an if else statement but than nothing worked anymore.

Thanks for help.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#vimeo_player_button').click(function(){
    $('#youtube_player').animate({
        marginLeft: '-1000px'
    });
});

$('#youtube_player_button').click(function(){
    $('#youtube_player').animate({
        marginLeft: '0'
    });
});    

var youtube = $('#youtube_player').animate({marginLeft: '0'});

if ('#youtube_player' = youtube) {
    $('#youtube_player_button').css('background-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 250)')
} else{
    $('#vimeo_player_button').css('background-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 250)')
};

});
```

Comment: just add/remove a class on click: http://jsfiddle.net/Vrxv9/5/  But your code should be refactorized a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to add a class `active` to your css:

```
.active {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 250);        
}
```

Then add `active`class to the clicked button as well as removing this class from other button:

```
$('#vimeo_player_button').click(function(){
    $('#youtube_player').animate({
        marginLeft: '-1000px'
    });
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('#youtube_player_button').click(function(){
    $('#youtube_player').animate({
        marginLeft: '0'
    });
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vrxv9/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You used the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), when you meant to use the [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), and comparing a selector as a string to a jQuery object makes no sense:

```
if ('#youtube_player' = youtube) {
```

Also, because you are only changing one [CSS property](http://api.jquery.com/css/) with jQuery you separate it with `,` instead of `:`

```
if ('#youtube_player' = youtube) {
    $('#youtube_player_button').css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 250)')
} else{
    $('#vimeo_player_button').css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 250)')
};
```

Lastly, you should do what A. Wolff said in the comments and just have a class that you add when you click the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

look at this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Vrxv9/10/

what i have done here is

- added active class on youtube button
- applied active class on selected button
- removed hove effect ( optional)

Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // intialization
     $('#youtube_player_button').addClass("active");

    $('#vimeo_player_button').click(function(){
        $('#youtube_player').animate({
            marginLeft: '-1000px'
        },1000,function(){
            $('#youtube_player_button').removeClass("active");
            $('#vimeo_player_button').removeClass("active");
            $('#vimeo_player_button').addClass("active");
        }); 

    });

    $('#youtube_player_button').click(function(){
        $('#youtube_player').animate({
            marginLeft: '0'
       },1000,function(){
            $('#vimeo_player_button').removeClass("active");
            $('#vimeo_player_button').removeClass("active");
            $('#youtube_player_button').addClass("active");
        });
    });    

});
```